# Trim values in array?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The match excel function takes an array or table as second parameter. Is there a way to trim the values of the array before feeding to match function?

I am looking for something like:

```vb
=MATCH("bat", TRIM(A1:A12), 0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The trim function returns a string, whilst your Match function is looking for an array. Perhaps this could work using array formula's (confirm your formula using ctrl+shift+enter instead of enter).

Answer (score 2):

It will work as an **array formula**:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.